# Почему после переноса сайта на другой сервер не отображаются картинки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

После переноса [сайта](http://ruchnoe-razmeschenie.ru/) на другой сервер не отображаются картинки (на главной под слайдером), хотя эти картинки есть и путь указан верно. На странице [контакты](http://ruchnoe-razmeschenie.ru/kontakty/) не отображается карта проезда в самом низу страницы. Почему так происходит? Как можно исправить?

Comment: .avia_transform .avia_animated_image, .avia_transform.avia_desktop .av-animated-generic {
    opacity: 0;
}

Comment: @Igor Оформите как ответ пожалуйста!

Comment: А вот с картой Google вопрос остается открытым...

Comment: В контайнере  `<div id="av_gmap_1" class="avia-google-map-container" data-mapid="1" style="height: 400px;"></div>` ничего нет. Разбирайтесь, как Вы создаете карту и почему это не происходит.